# TweenMax hover out is not triggering animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, gsap

I'm trying to change the width of a div with a border with a mouse hover on a link in another div, but the hover out is not returning the width back to 0.

```js
function over(){
  TweenMax.to($(".grid-item-20"), 1, {
        width: "50%",
        ease: Expo.easeInOut
  });
};

function out(){
  TweenMax.to($("grid-item-20"), 1, {
        width: "0",
        ease: Expo.easeInOut,
  });
};

$(".grid-item-17 a").hover(over, out);
```

```css
.grid-item-20 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  width: 0%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-item-17">

  <a href="#">Home</a>

</div>


<div class="grid-item-20">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `dot` on your selector

```
function out(){
  TweenMax.to($(".grid-item-20"), 1, {
        width: "0",
        ease: Expo.easeInOut,
  });
};
```

```js
function over(){
  TweenMax.to($(".grid-item-20"), 1, {
        width: "50%",
        ease: Expo.easeInOut
  });
};

function out(){
  TweenMax.to($(".grid-item-20"), 1, {
        width: "0",
        ease: Expo.easeInOut,
  });
};

$(".grid-item-17 a").hover(over, out);
```

```css
.grid-item-20 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  width: 0%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.0.1/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid-item-17">

  <a href="#">Home</a>

</div>


<div class="grid-item-20">

</div>
```